# how to move StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder to Async task or to an Intent service?? if Intent mean it would be much helpfull

Tags: android, android-asynctask, intentservice, android-strictmode

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
```

how to move `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder` to `AsyncTask` or  to an `IntentService`?? if Intent mean it would be much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy this way for debug mode only. Use it in AsyncTask.

Comment: Here's a good solution http://javatechig.com/android/download-image-using-asynctask-in-android